# Vertically Center a divider line to the Left of Styled Link Image

Tags: html, css, frontend

Alright, this one should be pretty easy for you front-end guys out there.  I have the styled purple link all set to go.  I'm just having trouble getting the vertical line to look OK.  Assume the line is `1px #000 solid`

[image]

I kind-of got it working making a `div` w/ a `bottom-border` and floating the styled link to the right.  If I do that, I can't seem to get there to be space between the divider line and the link.

Comment: Can we see the code in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following involves some extra markup and uses table-cells.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="leader">
        <b></b>
    </span>
    <span class="cell">
    <button>Sample Button</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted gray;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper .leader, .wrapper .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.wrapper .leader {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.wrapper .leader b {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper button {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8aSBA/

There are a few advantages to this approach:

1. You can control the spacing to the left and right of the horizontal line
2. Vertical alignment is independent of `font-size`, `line-height`
3. You don't need to specify the `width` of the button

Comment: Nice - thanks for the jsFiddle as well.  Actually got it working myself with a MUCH less eloquent solution that is VERY specific to the page.  But this is great.  Going to change my code to use this so I remember it for future reference.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a :before selector in css, though im not sure is compatable in < ie7

```
    .button:before { 
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
        content: "";
        float: left;
        height: 1px;
        margin-top: 12px;
        width: 59%;
    }
```